# Copy innerText of multiple element to Clipboard, using JS

Tags: javascript, foreach, clipboard, innertext

I have the below `HTML` code and I'm wanting to copy the innerText of each p element, to the clipboard, using Javascript. The innerText value is generated dynamically and randomly.

```html
<div class="colour-palette-showcase">
  <div class="colour-value">
    <div class="colour"></div>
    <p class="colour-value-text"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="colour-value">
    <div class="colour"></div>
    <p class="colour-value-text"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="colour-value">
    <div class="colour"></div>
    <p class="colour-value-text"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="colour-value">
    <div class="colour"></div>
    <p class="colour-value-text"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="colour-value">
    <div class="colour"></div>
    <p class="colour-value-text"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've stored the `.colour-value-text` to a variable, run a `forEach` and stored that to a new variable. But when I then try `document.execCommand('copy')`, it loops through and only copies the last one.
I'm guessing I need to store all the values to one array and then copy that to the clipboard. Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Any help much appreciated. This is my first attempt at a little JS project.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of code that copies all the `<p>`'s innerHTML to an array and from the array to a temporary `textarea` from where the complete value is copied to your clipboard:

```js
document.getElementById('copy-button').onclick = function() {
  let values = [];
  document.querySelectorAll('.colour-value-text').forEach( (p) => values.push( p.innerHTML ) );
  let text = document.createElement('textarea');
  document.body.appendChild(text);
  text.value = values.join(', ');
  text.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  text.parentNode.removeChild(text);
}
```

```html
  <div class="colour-palette-showcase">
           <div class="colour-value">
             <div class="colour"></div>
             <p class="colour-value-text">1</p>
           </div>
           <div class="colour-value">
             <div class="colour"></div>
             <p class="colour-value-text">2</p>
           </div>
           <div class="colour-value">
             <div class="colour"></div>
             <p class="colour-value-text">3</p>
           </div>
           <div class="colour-value">
             <div class="colour"></div>
             <p class="colour-value-text">4</p>
           </div>
           <div class="colour-value">
             <div class="colour"></div>
             <p class="colour-value-text">5</p>
           </div>
         </div>

  <button id="copy-button" type="button">copy</button>
```

Copied to clipboard:
`1, 2, 3, 4, 5`

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. I've used this within a function, so that when the 'c' key i pressed it fires and copies the values.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
 const range = document.createRange();
 range.selectNode(document.getElementById("example"));
 window.getSelection().addRange(range);
 document.execCommand("copy");
```

ofc you could use `document.getElementsByClassName("example");`